# Extract the first letter from each word in a sentence

Tags: java, string

I have developed a speech to text program where the user can speak a short sentence and then inserts that into a text box.

How do I extract the first letters of each word and then insert that into the text field?

For example if the user says: "Hello World". I want to insert HW into the text box.

Comment: Is this question about speech recognition, or do you already have the string that contains what the user said?

Comment: The user speaks and the content is stored into a string

  if (requestCode == RECOGNIZER_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
matches is the string which stores the input

Comment: Look into String API. There are plenty of methods which you can use like `charAt`, `split`, `substring`. Try something and when it will not work come back with your attempt.

Comment: I've tried this
 String testPrhase = matches.toString();      
            
            char strInput = testPrhase.charAt(1);
            
this takes the first letter of the first word but not the rest

Comment: use split, and split your string on space character.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a string, you could just split it using

```
input.split(" ") //splitting by space 
                 //maybe you want to replace dots, etc with nothing).
```

The iterate over the array:

```
for(String s : input.split(" "))
```

And then get the first letter of every string in a list/array/etc or append it to a string:

```
//Outside the for-loop:
String firstLetters = "";

// Insdie the for-loop:
firstLetters = s.charAt(0);
```

---

The resulting function:

```
public String getFirstLetters(String text)
{
  String firstLetters = "";
  text = text.replaceAll("[.,]", ""); // Replace dots, etc (optional)
  for(String s : text.split(" "))
  {
    firstLetters += s.charAt(0);
  }
  return firstLetters;
}
```

---

The resulting function if you want to use a list (ArrayList matches):

Basically you just use an array/list/etc as argument type and instead of **text.split(" ")** you just use the argument. Also, remove the line where you would replace characters like dots, etc.

```
public String getFirstLetters(ArrayList<String> text)
{
  String firstLetters = "";
  for(String s : text)
  {
    firstLetters += s.charAt(0);
  }
  return firstLetters;
}
```

Comment: Did you test your example? (1) Strings are immutable (2) you will be surprised with what `replaceAll(".", "")` does :)

Comment: Ah yeah, no I didn't. Forgot about escaping the dot, thanks for reminding!

Comment: text=text.replaceAll("\\.", "").replaceAll(",", "");

Comment: If you are going to use `replaceAll` then you can use `[,.]` as its argument to represent `,` OR `.`. There is no need to call this method two times separately for each of this characters.

Comment: I added the function. How do I make use it on a different method with the string variable matches

Comment: I edited the post to also contain a function which takes arrays as argument. (I hope you ment that)

Answer (score 0):

Use [split](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) to get an array separated words, then you can get first N characters with [substring](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))(0, N).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to extract the string, put it all into a list, and loop through

```
String[] old = myTextView.getText().split(" ");
String add="";
for(String s:old)
    add+=""+s.charAt(0);
myTextView.setText(add);
```

Comment: my bad, i meant it to be old

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sentence only contain `a-z and A-Z and " " to separate the words` , If you want an efficient way to do it, I suggest the below method.

```
public String getResult(String input){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : input.split(" ")){
        sb.append(s.charAt(0));         
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then write it to the text field.

```
jTextField.setText(getResult(input_String));
```

Comment: I tried it with my code
  String input = matches.toString();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for(String s : input.split(" ")){
                    sb.append(s.charAt(0));         
                }
             
and it didnt work - matches is the string which is storing the input. The output is just the whole sentence

Comment: try `String input = matches;`

Comment: what is the `matches` string ? can you paste it here or in the question ?

Comment: matches is this 
     final ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

Its the speech input